# Can you launch clock/timer app from iOS browser?

Tags: ios, iphone, browser, safari

Is there a url scheme or other mechanism for launching the timer or clock app in iOS from a browser?

**NOTE ABOUT DUPLICATE:** This question is **not** about how to do this via a native app. I am asking specifically if and how it's possible from the iOS **browser**. The question that this is marked as a duplicate of doesn't answer that question it answers the question of how to access the clock from a native app.

Comment: You can use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
  openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"clock-alarm:"]];
]; to open the clock app but I don't think you can place the timer in a Web browser instead you can use Notification i.e silent APNS.

Comment: @navroz thanks but I need to do this from the browser. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how APNS works but I need the timer to run/go off even when the browser is closed. Am I wrong about that not being possible with APNS?